# How to specify resulting size of OpenCV's CUDA version of pyrUp?

Tags: opencv

The third parameters of `cv::pyrUp` contains the "destination size" :

```
void cv::pyrUp( InputArray _src, OutputArray _dst, const Size& _dsz, int borderType )
```

Unfortunately, the CUDA version does not contain this parameter :

```
void cv::cuda::pyrUp(InputArray _src, OutputArray _dst, Stream& stream)
```

This parameter is important for creating image pyramids with non-power of two image sizes. For example, if I "pyramid down" (via `pyrDown`) from
a `90x90` image I get the following sizes:

```
90x90
45x45
23x23
12x12
 6x6
 3x3
 2x2
```

It is necessary to specify the size on `pyrUp` to get the odd sizes.
How are folks using `pyrUp` for odd size under CUDA?

Comment: Are you just pointing something out, or is there a question here?

Comment: Thanks, I edited and made the question explicit.

Comment: I would be also very interested by an answer. pyrUp is a crucial component of Laplacian pyramids and this even size restriction prevent any kind of difference computation between level[i] and pyrUp(level[i+1]) when level[i] has odd sizes.